# How do I implement store switcher through controllers?

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, store-view, admin-controller, scope-switcher

How do I implement store switcher through controllers instead of using block template to implement store view like this:

```
<forum_admin_adminhtml_forum_edit>
    <reference name="left">
         <block type="adminhtml/store_switcher" name="store_switcher" template="store/switcher.phtml" />
    </reference>
</forum_admin_adminhtml_forum_edit>
```

How can I implement store switch through controllers?

Comment: Please add more details to the question about what exactly you want to achieve with the controllers. That layout file merely generates some HTML content.

Answer (score 0):

In a controller you can achieve the same as the layout XML that you have provided with the following code after you have called `$this->loadLayout();` but before `$this->renderLayout();`:

```
$leftBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('left')
if (false != $leftBlock) {
    $storeSwitcherBlock = $this->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('adminhtml/store_switcher', 'store_switcher')
        ->setTemplate('store/switcher.phtml');
    $leftBlock->append($storeSwitcherBlock);
}
```

Comment: its not showing me store view..

Comment: Hi Dibyasri, did you ever get this to work? I'm curious to the solution you have found.